# Change a value of a pointer without calling for it in a function?

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I declare in *test.h* file

```
extern void test(int *ptr);
extern void myFunc();
extern int num;
```

I then include the h file in my *test1.c* file.

I write my functions in *test2.c*:

```
void myFunc( )
{
    test(&num);
}
void test(int *num )
{
    *num = 9;
}
```

in *test1.c* I write:

```
int num = 5;
myFunc();
```

My question is, how can i use the `num` variable/pointer in `test()` without passing it to `myFunc()`?

The file structure has to stay the same, thats why I am trying to refresh my C on this,

Than you

Comment: num is global. That's all there is to it....

Comment: The way you describe it now is a code smell.

Comment: Just to confirm - are you asking _how your code works_, or is there a problem with it (apart from the global smell)?

Comment: You already have "extern int num;" as global in the .h, so no need to declare int num; in test1.c, you only need to assign it the value and everything works as I think you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your scope.

```
void myFunc( )
{
    test(&num);
}
```

This function can't see the variable num unless num is global, and so it's GIGO (garbage in, garbage out).

I know it looks to you like num IS global, but here's the trick:

```
int num = 5;
myFunc();
```

I can't see the full code, but because of your formatting I'm guessing that this is using a local copy of num instead of the extern because you're declaring a *new* variable in local scope inside of the function where you're calling myFunc(). The extern isn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

if int num is global then any function can use it. Second case if you declare int num as local then I think it is an error or you can't access global num inside function where num is already present as local or write your complete code.